# Resize then crop PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

Ok, basically I want all images to be 170x170px squares.
Thus if an image is not a square i want it to be resized, and then cropped in the middle..

I have spent numerous hours playing with this and I am getting nowhere.. I have gotten it to crop a section of the bigger image etc, but i specifically need the image to be resized, then cropped..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// get image size of img
$x = @getimagesize($img);
// image width
$sw = $x[0];
// image height
$sh = $x[1];

if($sw > $sh) // Horizontal Rectangle?
{
  $newwidth = ($sw/$sh)*170;
  $newheight=170;   
  $x_pos = ($sw - $sh) / 2;
  $x_pos = ceil($x_pos);
  $y_pos=0;
}

else if($sh > $sw) // Vertical Rectangle?
{
  $newheight = ($sh/$sw)*170;
  $newwidth=170;
  $y_pos = ($sh - $sw) / 2;
  $y_pos = ceil($y_pos);
  $x_pos=0;
}
else //Already Square
{
  $newheight=170;
  $newwidth=170;
}

$im = @ImageCreateFromJPEG ($img) or // Read JPEG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromPNG ($img) or // or PNG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromGIF ($img) or // or GIF Image
$im = false; // If image is not JPEG, PNG, or GIF

if (!$im) {
  // We get errors from PHP's ImageCreate functions...
  // So let's echo back the contents of the actual image.
  readfile ($img);
} else {
  // Create the resized image destination
  $thumb = @ImageCreateTrueColor (170, 170);
  // Copy from image source, resize it, and paste to image destination
  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 180, $y_pos, 170, 170, $newwidth, 
    $newheight);
}
```

Comment: Ive provided a working script please check as solved (see below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needs some work, but it should give you enough to start with.

```
function crop($filename, $width, $height)
{
    // image resource, assuming it's PNG
    $resource = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    // resource dimensions
    $size = array(
        0 => imagesx($resource),
        1 => imagesy($resource),
    );
    // sides
    $longer  = (int)($size[0]/$width > $size[1]/$height);
    $shorter = (int)(!$longer);
    // ugly hack to avoid condition for imagecopyresampled()
    $src = array(
        $longer  => 0,
        $shorter => ($size[$shorter]-$size[$longer])/2,
    );
    // new image resource
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    // do the magic
    imagecopyresampled($new, $resource,
        0,  0,
        $src[0], $src[1],
        $width, $height,
        $size[$longer], $size[$longer]
    );

    // save it or something else :)
}
```

**Edit:** Trying to explain "ugly hack" above.

Two parameters in question are `$src_x` and `$src_y`, taken from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php):

> imagecopyresampled() will take an rectangular area from src_image of
>   width src_w and height src_h at position (src_x,src_y) and place it in
>   a rectangular area of dst_image of width dst_w and height dst_h at
>   position (dst_x,dst_y).

Meaning if `$filename`'s width is longer, `src_x` has to be `0`, and if height is longer, `src_y` has to be `0`. Translated into code, it would look something like this:

```
$src = ($size[$shorter]-$size[$longer])/2;

if ( $longer === 1 )
{
    imagecopyresampled($new, $resource,
        0,  0,
        $src, 0,
        $width, $height,
        $size[$longer], $size[$longer]
    );
}
else
{
    imagecopyresampled($new, $resource,
        0,  0,
        0, $src,
        $width, $height,
        $size[$longer], $size[$longer]
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly comment additionally on the hack you have utilized. Furthermore what was giving me the most hassle was all the different aspects of the imagecopyresampled() function... Thanks

Comment: See updated answer. "Ugly hack" is most likely a bad choice of words. The thing is I have a class for image processing, and to show an example for crop, I had to tweak the logic a bit. Hence, ugly hack :)

Answer (score 4):

ok, here's a working one;

```
<?
$img = 'leaf.jpg';
// get image size of img
$x = @getimagesize($img);

// image dimensions
$sw = $x[0];
$sh = $x[1];

//dest size
$dSize = 170;

//find smallerst part and get needed scale and offset
$yOff = 0;
$xOff = 0;
if($sw < $sh) {
  $scale = $dSize / $sw;
  $yOff = $sh/2 - $dSize/$scale/2; 
} else {
  $scale = $dSize / $sh;
  $xOff = $sw/2 - $dSize/$scale/2; 
}

$im = @ImageCreateFromJPEG ($img) or // Read JPEG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromPNG ($img) or // or PNG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromGIF ($img) or // or GIF Image
$im = false; // If image is not JPEG, PNG, or GIF

if (!$im) {
  // We get errors from PHP's ImageCreate functions...
  // So let's echo back the contents of the actual image.
  readfile ($img);
} else {
  // Create the resized image destination
  $thumb = @ImageCreateTrueColor ($dSize,$dSize);
  // Copy from image source, resize it, and paste to image destination
  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $im, 
    0, 0, 
    $xOff,$yOff,
    $dSize, $dSize, 
    $dSize / $scale ,$dSize / $scale);
}
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
//imagejpeg($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ImageMagic? If not, you should. 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: OP tag gd ... you can convince him maybe by some examples?

Comment: No.. ? This is principle can achieve exactly what I want.. id prefer to stick to what i know.. Thanks

Comment: I suppose I am not sure what you are using then. I can put some examples up, is is really simple. However, using ImageMagick means you will need it installed in your system that hosts the application. This is usually the case in *nix systems but not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out, I haven't yet but it looks promising.
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/