# how to crop image like facebook feed image of size 476X248px

Tags: php, resize, crop

I want to show preview of post published using page_id/feed Facebook graph API

When you see any post of facebook feed, they crop image in the dimension of 476X248px always. When I am resizing image of same dimensions, full image is resized while FB is cropping image using some calculations which I want to know how they are cropping image so I can show preview of Facebook feed image.

If image is not in the ratio of 600*315 FB does not show full image while it crops image in such a way that some part of image is not visible and when I look that image in console they cut it in the dimensions of 476X248px.

Please help me anyone how to crop that image like FB using PHP.

[original image of size 1000X400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVtEu.jpg)

[cropped image by FB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnTKl.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize then crop PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443320/resize-then-crop-php)

Comment: If the facebook feed only is an example, you should remove those tags. As far as I can tell, the question is simply about resizing and cropping images.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no its not same I dont want to crop it in square while I need it to be like FB feeds, please see my attached images and question again please, no facebook is not just example while it is everything with my question

Comment: You obviously need to modify the script to fit your needs. Are you expecting us to do all the work for you? SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no man I am just asking logic :) what Facebook is using to crop and resize image. I know php code to crop and resize but I need to know the logic to crop image in such a way

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to just crop the image to the dimensions facebook uses? You want to first declare the image and then apply the dimensions you're looking for.

```
<?php
$image = imagesource('example.png');
$size = min(imagewidth($im), imageheight($im));
$croppedimage = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
?>
```

Comment: when I am cropping image in this way then full image is resized but not as Facebook crops. full resized means after cropping complete image is visible.